# Configuring Firefox 23 and flash player 11 in Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, flash

I'm trying to get flash player working in my linux. No matter what I do I cannot seem to get it working. I have installed firefox 23 in `~/firefox`. Ive copied `libflashfplayer.so` to the following locations.

> [rbhat@rbhat-pc Downloads]$ sudo cp libflashplayer.so
>   /home/rbhat/.mozilla/plugins
>
> [rbhat@rbhat-pc Downloads]$ sudo cp libflashplayer.so
>   /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
>
> [rbhat@rbhat-pc Downloads]$ sudo cp libflashplayer.so
>   /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins
>
> [rbhat@rbhat-pc Downloads]$ sudo cp libflashplayer.so
>   /usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins-wrapped

None of them seem to work. I dont remember installing flash player being quite so annoying. Has something changed?

The flash player I downloaded is `flash-plugin-11.2.202.297-release.x86_64.rpm` and im using ***Oracle linux***.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I had the same issues in Fedora. I have so far not figured it out, so I now use Firefox for normal web use and Chrome (which comes with flash installed already) for when I need to use flash.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `~/firefox/browser/plugins/libflashplayer.so`. It was changed recently. I had to create folder `plugins` myself.

**EDIT**
I can be wrong, but...

Place where you should link your `libflashplayer.so` depends on how did you install Firefox. If installation was done with system tools (packet manager) than Firefox binaries and libraries will go to `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib` , etc. In this case linking flashplayer somewhere to `/usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins` probably will make sense, because Firefox was installed **system wide**.

But, if you download Firefox from [Mozilla site](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/) and unpack it manually to your home folder, than Firefox will be looking for libflashplayer link in the `~/firefox/browser/plugins/libflashplayer.so` because Firefox was installed for **single user**.

**UPDATE**

Here is [helpful article](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/05/15/why-you-may-have-lost-access-to-plugins-or-extensions-in-firefox-21/) which describes major changes in Firefox 21 including plugins directory.

Comment: I created a plugin directory under browser and copied it there. Still doesnt work

Comment: Make sure directory name is `plugins`, not `plugin`

Answer (score 0):

Put it here: `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/`.

```
$ sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/
```

Comment: @Ram Bhat Have you tried my solution?